# Inherited WPF custom control does not inherit parent Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, controltemplate

I've created a IconButton for use in WPF/XMAML. It should be able to display an Icon MDL2 Assets font on top and an text on bottom. It should have the appearance of an default WPF toolbar button. I decided to create a custom control which inherits from default WPF button.

So I created the custom control and added Dependency Properties for Text and the somehow cryptic MDL2IconCode:

```
public class IconButton : Button
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MDL2IconCodeProperty;

  public string Text
  {
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
  }


  public string MDL2IconCode
  {
    get { return (string)GetValue(MDL2IconCodeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MDL2IconCodeProperty, value); }
  }


  static IconButton()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IconButton),
                                             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(IconButton)));

    TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
                                               typeof(string),
                                               typeof(IconButton),
                                               new PropertyMetadata("Button text", OnTextChanged));

    MDL2IconCodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MDL2IconCode",
                                                       typeof(string),
                                                       typeof(IconButton),
                                                       new PropertyMetadata("\uf13e", OnIconTextChanged));
  }

  static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject o,
                            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var iconButton = o as IconButton;
    if (iconButton == null)
    {
      return;
    }
    string newText = e.NewValue as string;
    iconButton.Text = newText;
  }

  static void OnIconTextChanged(DependencyObject o,
                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var iconButton = o as IconButton;
    if (iconButton == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    string newText = e.NewValue as string;
    iconButton.MDL2IconCode = newText;
  }
}
```

The ResourceDictionary of *Generic.xaml* looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI.CustomControls">


  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}" 
         BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}">
          <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{TemplateBinding MDL2IconCode}"
                         FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                         FontSize="16"
                         x:Name="iconTextBlock"/>
              <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                         Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                         x:Name="textTextBlock"/>
            </StackPanel>

          </Button>

        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The button looks as it should.

But the command binding in XAML isn't working anymore. But it should work, as per inheritance it still is a button..

Maybe anyone has an idea what to add to make the command binding work?

Comment: The `ControlTemplate` of a `Button` shouldn't generally speaking include another `Button`. Did you consider to base your `Style` on `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` and set the `Content` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the command of the `Button` inside of your control template to the templated parent.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}">
   <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
           Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
           CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}"
           CommandTarget="{TemplateBinding CommandTarget}">
      <!-- ...other code. -->
   </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

> But it should work, as per inheritance it still is a button..

No. The `Button` inside of your control template does not magically bind to the corresponding properties of its templated parent, regardless if it is derived from `Button` or any other control. You will have to do so for other dependency properties like the `CommandParameter` as well.

Please also note that [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is an optimized binding that does not have all capabilities of the more powerful [`Binding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) markup extension. Consequently, when `TemplateBinding` does not work, e.g. in two-way binding scenarios, you can use `TemplatedParent` like this:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MyDependencyProperty}
```

For more information, you can refer to the [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, with the Command TemplateBinding it's finally working.

Comment: But now I've noticed it's only working when I add the Text for an IconButton in the XAML designer. It doesn't work when I bind Text to a ViewModel property. Ìs `INotifyPropertyChanged` not supported by ControlTemplate binding?

Comment: Using `TemplatedParent` didn't fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The `ControlTemplate` of a `Button` shouldn't include another `Button`.

You should template your control to *look* like a `Button` if that's what you want:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}">
                <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding MDL2IconCode}"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                           FontSize="16"
                                           x:Name="iconTextBlock"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                           x:Name="textTextBlock"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="#80DADADA" Property="BorderBrush"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFB6BDC5" Property="Background"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="#80DADADA" Property="BorderBrush"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFB6BDC5" Property="Background"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="#90006CD9" Property="BorderBrush"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="#400080FF" Property="Background"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Property="Foreground"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It will then behave like any other `Button` which means that you can bind its `Command` property as usual:

```
<local:IconButton Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
```