# TemplateBinding not working on INotifyPropertyChanged in WPF custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I recently [created an IconButton in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014150/inherited-wpf-custom-control-does-not-inherit-parent-command) as CustomControl. It is using TemplateBinding for the DependencyProperties:

**IconButton.cs**

```
public class IconButton : Button
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MDL2IconCodeProperty;

  public string Text
  {
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
  }


  public string MDL2IconCode
  {
    get { return (string)GetValue(MDL2IconCodeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MDL2IconCodeProperty, value); }
  }


  static IconButton()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IconButton),
                                             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(IconButton)));

    TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
                                               typeof(string),
                                               typeof(IconButton),
                                               new PropertyMetadata("Button text", OnTextChanged));

    MDL2IconCodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MDL2IconCode",
                                                       typeof(string),
                                                       typeof(IconButton),
                                                       new PropertyMetadata("\uf13e", OnIconTextChanged));
  }

  static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject o,
                            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var iconButton = o as IconButton;
    if (iconButton == null)
    {
      return;
    }
    string newText = e.NewValue as string;
    iconButton.Text = newText;
  }

  static void OnIconTextChanged(DependencyObject o,
                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var iconButton = o as IconButton;
    if (iconButton == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    string newText = e.NewValue as string;
    iconButton.MDL2IconCode = newText;
  }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI.CustomControls">


  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}" 
         BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconButton}">
          <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                  Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
                  CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}"
                  CommandTarget="{TemplateBinding CommandTarget}">
            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{TemplateBinding MDL2IconCode}"
                         FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                         FontSize="16"
                         x:Name="iconTextBlock"/>
              <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                         Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                         x:Name="textTextBlock"/>
            </StackPanel>

          </Button>

        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But it works only half. I soon realized that binding to the DependencyProperties only works from the XAML designer but not from a ViewModel. So, when I set the Text property in the designer it works. But binding to it from a ViewModel, the property is neither set initially nor updated on INotifyPropertyChanged events.

So as a test I changed the TemplateBinding of Text property to

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text}
```

But it didn’t help.

What could be the problem in my code?

Is INotifyPropertyChanged supported by WPF custom controls with TemplateBinding at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you set new values of `Text` and `MDL2IconCode` in a way which breaks the `Binding`, so changes are not propagated to UI.

```
iconButton.Text = newText;
....
iconButton.MDL2IconCode = newText;
```

The correct way is to use `SetCurrentValue` method that changes the effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings, and styles will continue to work.

```
static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var iconButton = o as IconButton;
    if (iconButton == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    string newText = e.NewValue as string;
    iconButton.SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, newText);
}

static void OnIconTextChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var iconButton = o as IconButton;
    if (iconButton == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    string newText = e.NewValue as string;
    iconButton.SetCurrentValue(MDL2IconCodeProperty, newText);
}
```

But if you don't have any special logic in `OnTextChanged` and `OnIconTextChanged` then you can get rid of `PropertyChangedCallbacks` and it will still work.

```
TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
                                                   typeof(string),
                                                   typeof(IconButton),
                                                   new PropertyMetadata("Button text"));

MDL2IconCodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MDL2IconCode",
                                                           typeof(string),
                                                           typeof(IconButton),
                                                           new PropertyMetadata("\uf13e"));
```